# Bash scripting and executable scripting

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to run django combined with Jupyter in a virtual environment. The following code gets the job done:

```
source home/sujith/dev/django/bin/activate  && python home/sujith/dev/django/src/manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

I saved the script as `django.sh` in my home directory. If I run `./django.sh` the notebook pops up.

I tried saving this in `/bin`, but I couldn't run it. I want to type `django` instead of `./django.sh` in my terminal and have the above script run.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Relative paths won't work from `/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`... Change `./dev/django/bin/activate` to absolute path, e.g. `/home/sijith/dev/django/bin/activate`.

Comment: @ponsfrilus My bad. I did try using the absolute path. It said django command not found :l

Comment: @Sujith An absolute path needs to start with `/`.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog. So if I do that, it'll work? No need do type .sh?

Comment: @Sujith First see if you can run it as `django.sh`. To run it without the .sh extension you need to save the script without it, that is save it as `django` instead of `django.sh`.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog It works. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [ponsfrilus said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286076/bash-scripting-and-executable-scripting?noredirect=1#comment2182624_1286076), you must use absolute paths (paths starting with `/`) for your commands to work from `/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. So your script should become:

```
source /home/sujith/dev/django/bin/activate && python /home/sujith/dev/django/src/manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

To run it as `django`, you must save your script in a file named `django` with `#/bin/bash` on the top of the file. Then make it executable by running:

```
chmod u+x /path/to/django
```

where `/path/to/django` is the absolute path to your script.

Finally, move your script to `/bin` by running:

```
sudo mv /path/to/django /bin
```

You should now be able to run your script just by typing `django` in your terminal.

---

Another, much simpler, option is to create an alias for your script, by adding the following at the end of your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias django='source /home/sujith/dev/django/bin/activate && python /home/sujith/dev/django/src/manage.py shell_plus --notebook'
```

Then close your terminal and reopen it or run the following for the alias to take effect:

```
source .bashrc
```